# Find a path between two values in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, search, tree, networkx

I am trying to find the path between two elements in a **dictionary**.

Let me explain the situation. Using **NetworkX** I created a *graph* and using `bfs_successors` and `dfs_successors` I created two *trees*, saved in two *dictionaries*, as you can see:

```
BFS = nx.bfs_successors(mazePRIM, start)
print(dict(BFS))

DFS = nx.dfs_successors(mazePRIM, start)
print(DFS)
```

and I get this:

```
{(0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 2)], (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 2): [(0, 3)]}

{(0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 2)], (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 2): [(0, 3)]}
```

Now I need to get the "path" between the root/start, (0,0), and an end node, for example (1,3). How can I get it?

So I need a function to search the end node and to return the path between start and end.

And is it possible to write it this way?

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Boundary: I need to use **dfs** and **bfs**. In fact, as I created the dfs-tree and the bfs-tree, I want to locate one node (which will be the end node) and reconstruct its path.

Thank you in advance

Comment: To whoever voted down to this question: please tell me why, I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: Is `shortest_path` what you're looking for?  https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html

Comment: Sort of. I am trying to, but I want to use dfs and bfs

Comment: And, as I created the bfs-tree and the dfs-tree, I want to locate one node (which will be the end node) and reconstruct its path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea of networkx (although I've never used it) is probably that you'd use a function like `shortest_path` to find the path between two specific nodes, and you'd only use the dfs/bfs functions if you want an exhaustive list of all the reachable nodes.

That said, if you wanted to roll your own DFS using the dictionary you got from those functions, here's an example:

```
>>> from typing import Dict, List, Tuple
>>>
>>>
>>> def dfs(
...     graph: Dict[Tuple[int, int], List[Tuple[int, int]]],
...     path: List[Tuple[int, int]],
...     target: Tuple[int, int]
... ) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
...     """Given a graph and a starting path, return the
...     complete path through the graph to the target."""
...     if path[-1] == target:
...         return path
...     if path[-1] not in graph:
...         return []
...     for node in graph[path[-1]]:
...         if node in path:
...             continue
...         maybe_path = dfs(graph, path + [node], target)
...         if len(maybe_path):
...             return maybe_path
...     return []
...
>>>
>>> print(dfs(
...     {(0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 0): [(1, 1)], (1, 1): [(1, 2)], (1, 2): [(0, 2), (1, 3)], (0, 2): [(0, 3)]},
...     [(0, 0)],
...     (1, 3)
... ))
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```